# java import user defined package - error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, package

My directory structure is as follows:

```
/WorkingDirectory
    MyCollection.java
    /au/edu/au
        /UserInterface
            UserInterface.java
        /Collection
            Album.java
            CDAlbum.java
            DVDAlbum.java
            CollectionFactory.java
```

Where Album.java is an interface implemented by CDAlbum.java and DVDAlbum.java. Each .java file has the appropriate

```
package au.edu.uow.UserInterface;
```

or

```
package au.edu.uow.Collection;
```

line.

In UserInterface.java I declare an ArrayList of type Album, which gives me compile errors of

```
.\au\edu\uow\UserInterface\UserInterface.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    private ArrayList<Album> myCollection;
                      ^
symbol:   class Album
location: class UserInterface
```

I am compiling from MyCollection.java, which has import statements for both packages.

what is causing this error? I tried adding

```
import au.edu.uow.Collection
```

to UserInterface.java, but to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need either:

```
import au.edu.uow.Collection.*;
```

or:

```
import au.edu.uow.Collection.Album;
```

Using wildcard imports is more convenient but some consider this a bad practice.  This is a matter of style; decide for yourself.

It is also considered good style for package names to be in all-lower-case, although this is not enforced by the compiler.

Comment: yeah, i literally just figured that out then by looking at some other code, now i feel like a fool.

thanks for the quick response, mate XD

Comment: @thorium220 If you think this answer is correct and works for you, you should accept it and upvote it.

Comment: @rajesh i know, but i couldn't when i posted my above comment - <10mins had elapsed since jimN posted. i also don't have enough rep to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

So, you folder structure looks like `/au/edu/au` & your trying to import from `au.edu.uow`

Apart from what JimN has suggested, I think you'll find that Java will complain that te `package` doesn't exist or the files in `/au/edu/au` are in the wrong `package`

Either change the directory structure or `package` structure to match each other